# Read files from sub-folders using camel ftp

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Is it possible to read files from sub-folders using Camel-ftp?
 ex. i connect to an ftp server like

```
sftp://xxx:22/ftp?
```

In this i might have an sub-folder structure like /ftp/test/...

Can camel read files under the sub-folders? I tried to do, but camel doesn't seem to read from sub-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using recursive=true . FTP SFTP endpoint extending GenericFileEndpoint and have same properties like file [endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: something like flatten or recursive in file2 component. I tried to add recursive= true. Still it was not reading files from sub-directory. my full url looks like ´´from("sftp://xxxx:22/ftp?password=*&username=*&binary=false?recursive=true&delay=${pollingDelay}&moveFailed=.error&move=.done&preMove=${IN_PROGRESS_DIR}&include=.*.zip&sortBy=file:modified&readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=${readLockTimeout}&readLockCheckInterval=${readLockCheckInterval}&idempotent=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true")´´

Comment: Thanks @c0ld. I used wrong syntax when using recursive. 

    &binary=false&recursive=true whereas i was using `&binary=false?recursive=true`